# callback from workerRole when task is completed

Tags: azure

I  have a workerrole which creates a PDF document. I pass the workerRole the needed data trough a queue, the worker role creates a PDF document, stores it in a BLOB, but how can I send the BLOB address back to the website to inform the user where to go to download the PDF?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's a typical scenario for the [Correlation Identifier pattern](http://www.enterpriseintegrationpatterns.com/CorrelationIdentifier.html).

When the worker role is done, it should **send back a message over a queue** indicating that the document is ready. You can use a Correlation Identifier (such as a document id) to indicate on the DocumentReadyEvent message which original request this event relates to.

You could also go the route of full [CQRS](http://abdullin.com/cqrs) and simply update a view-specific table that includes the new document, and let the web site query from that.

Answer (score 1):

You could do it the other way around using a common naming framework. Let the website/user application choose the name and location of the blob based on some standard convention. The site/app can then occasionally check for the blob via an http request.

Answer (score 0):

But, do you want to inform the web user in real time about the ready document?

You can do lot of things, for example you can create a table partitioned by "user id" and store the url of the finished documents there, and set up an ajax call that checks in background the content of that table for that user regularly, and when it founds a new one that has not been "viewed" yet, show a warning with a download link.

Just an idea.